# Module not found after reinstall

Tags: python, error-handling, package

Package not found an error:

[image: package not found an error]

Does anyone know what happened or how to fix it? It just randomly happened and I have no clue how it started.

As in the screenshot, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module, but I still can't find the package. This happens with other packages too.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple versions of python ... you can see the paths are different

[image]

you should do

`/path/to/correct/python -m pip install colorama`

that will ensure it is installed for /path/to/correct/python